# Xcode downloads client crash reports for string interpolation (_StringGuts.append)

Tags: swift, cocoa, foundation

Xcode contains several crash reports downloaded from users of my app. Thread 1 apparently crashes while performing a string interpolation. All the other threads only contain calls to system code.

The `String.appendingPathComponent(_:)` that appears in the stacktrace is defined as follows:

```
extension String {

    func appendingPathComponent(_ pathComponent: String) -> String {
        return pathComponent == "" ? self : self == "" || self == "/" ? "\(self)\(pathComponent)" : "\(self)/\(pathComponent)"
    }

}
```

What could cause such a crash?

```
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x00007ff81566f9df __CFStringEncodeByteStream + 120 (CFStringEncodings.c:692)
1   Foundation                      0x00007ff8164c95aa -[NSString(NSStringOtherEncodings) getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:] + 204 (NSStringEncodings.m:341)
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00007ff822c6c1e0 String.UTF8View._foreignDistance(from:to:) + 208 (StringUTF8View.swift:507)
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00007ff822c56715 _StringGuts.append(_:) + 1445 (StringGutsRangeReplaceable.swift:191)
4   MyApp                           0x00000001010c3c0f String.appendingPathComponent(_:) + 15 (<compiler-generated>:0)
```

Comment: Oh boy, don't nest conditional operators like this. This happens to parse the way you probably expected it to, but it's pretty non-obvious that it's the case, and is an easy source of bugs. That would only cause a logic error in this case, not a crash, though.

Comment: Unrelated to the crash you should be aware that your logic is incorrect. If `self` is equal to something like `"foo/"` and/or `pathComponent` starts with a `/`, you will end up with two slashes in the result. I would replace your implementation with `return (self as NSString).appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)`.

Comment: Thanks, but in my code I already make sure that the strings have the proper format. I'm trying to avoid using `NSString.appendingPathComponent` because it's used a lot in my code and it's quite slow in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Your crash could be due to multiple reasons:

1. Unsafe string manipulation - Most likely
2. String encoding issue
3. Thread safety issue - Less likely

You might wanna try a safer string manipulation method. And as long as you're dealing with directories..

**Try this**

```swift
extension String {
    func appendingPathComponent(_ pathComponent: String) -> String {
        return (
            pathComponent == "" ?
            self :
                URL(filePath: self)
                .appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
                .path
        )
    }
}
```

> This also handles all conditions in order for you to remove the boilerplate code of your nested conditional operators.

Comment: There's no need for the parentheses around the `return` statement.

Comment: Sure, just for visualization.

Comment: Thanks, but in my code I already make sure that the strings have the proper format. I'm trying to avoid using NSString.appendingPathComponent and converting to and from `URL` because it's used a lot in my code and it's quite slow in comparison. Would you mind explaining what "Unsafe string manipulation" means in the provided code? What's unsafe about it? And how would I avoid the "String encoding issue"?

Comment: Unsafe string manipulation in this context means that the string `self` or `pathComponent` might be corrupted or invalid. This could be due to problematic characters in one of the strings, data handling, memory issues, etc..  **Please provide your full code that handles the string format and other aspects to better help you**